# Writting a first order formula for soritng problem

Tags: logic

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm), we say a sequence $A$ of numbers are sorted, if and only if

1. Output should be in increasing/decreasing order.
2. Output should be a permutation of input.

Now, i try to describe above two conditions in First-order logic. It's easy to describe 1,

$$\forall i,j\in \mathbb{N}, i\leq j\implies A[i] \leq A[j]$$
But my problem is, how we can describe 2 in logic?

Comment: You need an additional function symbol for the input, say $B$. Then observe that every component of $B$ appears in $A$, and *vice versa.* Could you see how to express it?

Comment: No, I can't express your idea in logic.

Comment: Do you know the definition of onto functions? Could you try to express it in first-order logic?

Comment: Yes, I know, also i can express it in first-order logic.